# Syncing a SharePoint site's files with the OneDrive desktop client: using a personal Microsoft Account

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sync, onedrive, synchronisation

Example scenario:

- Let's say we have a regular 365 tenant called "TenantCompany", that have a SharePoint Online site such as: https://tenantcompany.sharepoint.com/sites/OurCompanySite/
- "User A" with 365 tenant login **user_a@tenantcompany.com**, shares the "OurCompanySite" out to an external user, "User B": **userb@outlook.com**
- **userb@outlook.com** is simply a regular **personal** "Microsoft Account".  "User B" does not have a 365 account at all.
- **userb@outlook.com** can browse the files in their web browser at: https://tenantcompany.sharepoint.com/sites/OurCompanySite/Shared%20Documents/ - this works fine
- But when **userb@outlook.com** tries to click **"Sync"**, to have the files sync down to their desktop computer using OneDrive, I get error when trying to login with the OneDrive desktop client:

  - ***"You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead."***

---

**Question 1: Is it even meant to be technically possible for **userb@outlook.com** to sync the files from the "OurCompanySite" SharePoint site?  Purely with their personal Microsoft account?**

I'm sure I've seen this work in the past, but it was very inconsistent from all my experiments.  It seemed to work like 15% of the time.  And sometimes after it was working for a while it would stop.

To start with I'm simply trying to figure out whether this is even meant to be possible or not, i.e. a simply "yes" or "no" answer to this question.  Because without this, trying to answer #2 has been very hard...

---

**Question 2: If it can be done, what it the best procedure to get it working?**

---

**Question 3: If the answer is "No", why does Microsoft display the **"Sync"** button to begin with?  Other buttons that they can't use are normally hidden.**

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is not possible. The Guest user must be using an M365 Work or School account.

The documentation is available [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/onedrive/b2b-sync#b2b-sync-requirements).